# Counting cards game

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a card counting function in javascript.  Each card is assigned a value according to the table below. When the count is positive, the player should bet high. When the count is zero or negative, the player should bet low.

(i) if cards are  2, 3, 4, 5, 6 then count change =(+1);

(ii) if cards are 7,8,9 then count change =0;

(iii)if cards are  10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', then count change = (-1);

Here is my function:

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  {
   case 2:
   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
  return count++;
   case 7:
   case 8:
   case 9:
  return count;
   case 10:
   case 'J':
   case 'Q':
   case 'K':
   case 'A':
  return count--;
 }
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

From the last line of the code, I was anticipating to get a '0', but instead it gives me a '1'. Can anyone enlightens me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the expression count++ (or count--) returns the counter before the update (and updates it as a side effect).
If you want to return the counter after updating you should use the ++ (or --) before the counter.
For example, if the count is 1 -

- If you return count++ then 1 will be returned and as a side effect count will increase to 2.
- If you return ++count then count will first increase and then be returned so 2 will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {

  if (card >= 2 && card <= 6) {
    count += 1
  }
  else if (card >= 7 && card <= 9) {
    count += 0
  } else {
    count -= 1
  }
  return count <= 0 ? `${count} Hold` : `${count} Bet`;

}
```